# How to estimate 2SLS using ratio of covariance in a presence of a vector of exogenous variables?

Tags: regression, least-squares, covariance, instrumental-variables, 2sls

I am trying to estimate 2SLS using some simulated data, just to understand the theory behind it. First, I did it with just one endogenous variable ($X$) and one instrument ($Z$). Supposing the classic model

$$Y_i= \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i+u_i$$
I used an instrument $Z_i$ and run the regression $$X_i=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1Z_i+v_i$$ so I got the predicted values of $\hat{X_i}$ and used it to get the estimators, regressing $Y_i$ on it: $$Y_i= \beta_0 + \beta_1\hat{X_i}+u_i$$
In this way, I got the estimation of $\hat{\beta_1}$. Ok!

Then I wanted to get the same value using the ratio of covariances. Hence, I evaluated: $$\hat{\beta_1}=\frac{Cov(Y_i,Z_i) }{Cov(X_i,Z_i)}$$
It worked. **Perfect.**

Now I want to do the same, but including an exogenous variable ($W$) on the initial model:$$Y_i= \gamma_0 + \gamma_1X_i+ \gamma_2W_i+u_i$$.

I did the two stages (using the same instrument, $Z$) and estimated $\hat{\gamma_0},\hat{\gamma_1}$  and $\hat{\gamma_2}$. Then, I want to confirm the values, as I did previoulsy.

**My question is: How can I estimate $\hat{\gamma_0},\hat{\gamma_1}$  and $\hat{\gamma_2}$ using the covariance ratio?**